# What the value should I input on property with Class as its Datatype in c#?

Tags: c#

So, guys, Let's say there are 3 classes (Program.cs , Animal.cs and Dog.cs)

On Animal.cs , 
I will a simple attribute/methods something like this :

```
public class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

    public void Hello()
    {
    Console.WriteLine("Hello, What's Up!!!");
    }  
}
```

Then on Dog.cs

```
    public class Dog : Animal
        {
            public string Address { get; set; }
            public bool IsCute { get; set; }
            public Animal FirstVariable { get; set; }
            public Animal SecondVariable { get; set; }
            public Dog ThirdVariable { get; set; }


        public void Look(string name, int age, string address, bool isCute)
        {
        Name = name;
        Age = age;
        Address = address;
        IsCute = isCute;
        }

            public void Sight(Animal firstVariable, Animal secondVariable, Dog thirdVariable)
            {
            FirstVariable = firstVariable;
            SecondVariable = secondVariable;
            ThirdVariable = thirdVariable;
            }
    }
    }
```

Finally, on Program.cs

```
    Dog firstobject = new Dog();
    firstobject.Look("Persian",5,"Apple Residence",True);
    firstobject.Sight(A, B, C);
```

**So, what should I input on A, B and C ?**

Coz I still really confuse about a Class becoming a Datatype and what value should I put in.

Because Datatype AFAIK is usually has a value of string/integer/double/etc.

And please give me some examples, if you could,

I would really appreciate it.

Comment: If you look at your Dog.cs, you will see that Sight accepts an `Animal` as the first parameter, an `Animal` as the second parameter, and a `Dog` as the third parameter. So, you would use `Animal`,`Animal`,`Dog`

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you should know:

1. When a class is instantiated, the instance of that class is referred to as an object. Classes are typically referred to as reference types. In OO jargon - If you were making cookies, then a cookie cutter would be the class, and the object would be the cookie that comes out of the oven.
2. The way that a reference object is created is by using the new keyword which calls the constructor. The compiler supplies a default constructor for you if you don't define one.

So, your code does not define any constructors for either class. This means that the default constructor is defined for you by the compiler. The default constructor sets each field and property to its respective default value. The default value for reference types is null and the default value for value types like int is zero. The default value for bool is also zero, but is interpreted as false.

If you want your object to hold values other than the default values, then you will have to write your own constructor. You can write a constructor that takes no arguments, which means that you will be overriding the default constructor provided by the compiler. Or, you can write a constructor that takes one or more arguments that can be used to initialize the object in some way.

In order to properly call the Dog.Sight method, you need to pass the objects it is expecting. For example:

```
Dog firstobject = new Dog();
firstobject.Look("Persian",5,"Apple Residence",True);
// Create 2 animals and a dog object - because that is what is expected.
Animal A1 = new Animal();
Animal A2 = new Animal();
Dog D1 = new Dog();
firstobject.Sight(A1, A2, D1);
```

Since Dog is a derived class of Animal, a Dog object could be passed instead. This is known as polymorphism. For example:

```
Dog firstobject = new Dog();
firstobject.Look("Persian",5,"Apple Residence",True);
// Create 3 dogs.
Dog D1 = new Dog();
Dog D2 = new Dog();
Dog D3 = new Dog();
firstobject.Sight(D1, D2, D3);
```

There are some other things you need to know:

1. You have defined your classes with public properties. That is fine for a test project. But, one of the principles behind good OO is encapsulation. That means not declaring fields as public and only declaring a limited number of properties as public. Rather than exposing all the properties as public and then doing something with those fields outside the class, the class should encapsulate that functionality and only expose the methods that perform the necessary functionality.
2. Naming convention - FirstVariable, SecondVariable, and ThirdVariable mean little. What are they for? Anyone that comes along after you to try and maintain the code would have no idea. Try to come up with better field, property, and parameter names.

Comment: It's my intention not to include the constructor and using that variable name,
But thanks for pointing out

Comment: So, What do you call about what you just explained ?
What's the keyword to search this kind of things on Google ?

Comment: Object Oriented Development (OOD) or Object Oriented Programming (OOP). Wikipedia has a decent introductory [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, a class is a valid type just like int, string, etc.

You've already shown that you can declare a variable of a class type - `firstobject` is such a variable.

If you want to pass another Animal in to firstobject.Sight, you would first construct an instance of that class (i.e. an object) and then pass the object.  You could do it in a few ways:

```
Dog lassie = new Dog();
lassie.Name = "Lassie";

Dog krypto = new Dog();
krypto.Name = "Krypto";
krypto.IsCute = true;

Animal grumpyCat = new Animal();
grumpyCat.Name = "Grumpy Cat :(";
grumpyCat.Age = 7;

Animal dumbo = new Animal();
dumbo.Name = "Dumbo";
dumbo.Age = 75;

// Call a method on Lassie, passing in three other objects as parameters:
lassie.Sight(dumbo, grumpyCat, krypto);
```

You can also use an abbreviated syntax if you want to create object literals (i.e. create objects that you don't assign to a local variable):

```
lassie.Sight( new Animal() { Name: "Nessie"}, new Animal() { Name: "Bigfoot"}, new Dog {Name: "Taco Bell Dog", IsCute: false} );
```

Comment: So, What do you call about what you just explained ?
What's the keyword to search this kind of things on Google ?